# dragging/swiping gives a jerk if mousedown on a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, custom-events

I am working on the following code for creating a custom mouse based swipe event.

Now I want to pass `$('.element')` as the value to the 'mousedown' event when 'o:swipe' event is initiated so that 'mousedown' and 'mousemove' event work only upon the element I selected for the swipe event and not on any children element to `$('.element')`.

Currently if any children is placed inside the `$('.element')` then, 'mousedown' event takes it as a target and its pageX position if clicked on it , but I want the same of `$('.element')`, hence I require to pass a value from 'o:swipe' event to 'mousedown' event.

Currently it give jerk on move when clicked on any children of `$('.element')`.

Here is the [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/mororigewo)

```
$(function(){

    var te = {};

    $('body').on('mousedown', function(e) {

        var ti = e;
        te.target = $(ti.target);
        te.bX = ti.pageX;
        te.lastX = te.target.position().left;

    }).on('mousemove', function(e) {

        te.eX = e.pageX;
        te.position = te.lastX + ( -1 * (te.bX - te.eX));
        te.target.trigger('o:swipe',{ pos : te.position });

    }).on('mouseup', function(e) { te = {}; });


    // ============ SWIPE EVENT SECTION ================

    $('.element').on('o:swipe', function(e, to) {

        $(e.target).closest($(this)).css( 'left' , to.pos + 'px');

    });

});
```

Comment: try to bind element with $(".element") instead of body. I have checked your demo there is no jerk.

Comment: @farhan then the custom event 'o:swipe' remains of no use, as i will have to bind the default events to each element with which i want this functionality

Comment: in which browser or device you are testing

Comment: @farhan i tested it on chrome, firefox, ie on desktop and the result is the same. but as of code, it is not hindered by the browser, friend